# JRE Link for Java Web Start JNLP Files

Tags: java, java-web-start

When adding a "j2se" line to your JNLP file like below so that Web Start downloads an appropriate JRE, what exactly should be stored at that location? (i.e. Should that URL have a single file/installer, zip, extracted JRE, or just the exe that downloads when you click the button on https://www.java.com/en/download/windows-64bit.jsp , etc.)

The link below (mostly what I see in examples but obviously old) just redirects to a URL that gives a 404 (another "sun.com" link). I've searched the Web Start docs and so far I haven't been able to locate anything helpful.

```
<j2se version="1.8+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

I can't use a web link, so I'll need to either set up a private JRE download site to use here, or find an alternative solution.